# C# RESTful service single request with multiple responses

Tags: c#, web-services, http, rest

I was wondering if it's possible to send one HTTP request and receive the response body in multiple fragments.  Does the HTTP protocol allow for this?

Comment: By 'In Parts' - do you mean 'Chunking'?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Anything? http://google.com, maybe?

Comment: Yes, of course. Otherwise I do not ask my question here ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API has a class [PushStreamContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.pushstreamcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which will allow you to send data back in chunks to the response stream.